# Drawing a circle on a plane surface

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm building a voxel game and I want to simulate the waves that are created in the water. The way I want to do is to draw circles that are growing during a short period of time. To give you a visual clue of what I want to create is something like this:

[image: Circles simulating water waves]

I have created a plane with a blue material and I have the following script named WaterWave.cs:

```
public static class WaterWave
{
   public static void DrawCircle(this GameObject container, float radius, float lineWidth)
   {
       var segments = 360;
       var line = container.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();

       line.useWorldSpace = false;  // use parent's coordenates
       line.startWidth = lineWidth;
       line.endWidth = lineWidth;
       line.positionCount = segments + 1;

       var pointCount = segments + 1; // add extra point to make startpoint and endpoint the same to close the circle
       var points = new Vector3[pointCount];

       for (int i = 0; i < pointCount; i++)
       {
           var rad = Mathf.Deg2Rad * (i * 360f / segments);
           points[i] = new Vector3(Mathf.Sin(rad) * radius, 0, Mathf.Cos(rad) * radius);
       }

       line.SetPositions(points);
   }
}
```

Then I create another script (WaveTest.cs) with the following code:

```
public class WaveTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        WaterWave.DrawCircle(this.gameObject, 5.0f, 1.5f);
    }
}
```

And finally I assign both scripts (WaterWave.cs and WaterTest.cs) to the blue plane object, but nothing appears on the surface of the plane.

Any idea of how to create the 2D circles that appear on top of the blue plane surface?

Comment: Would it not be easier to use a ParticleSystem with the particle material being the circle and its size increase over lifetime?, Further more you can have a single ParticleSystem for it and just set where specific particles from a pool are positioned so its all done on a single Draw Call.

Comment: Thank you @Akabase for the recommendation. Any idea where I can read further on your approach?